# Fair die: Probability of rolling $2$ before rolling $3$ or $5$

Tags: probability

Independent trials consisting of rolling a fair die are performed, what is the probability that $2$ appears before $3$ or $5?$

There are $36$ cases if we take two trials like $11 12 13 14 15 16 
..21 22 23 24 25 26..31 32 33 34 35 36$ like this . But two has occurred before , so total $6$ cases , favourable just two$(23 25)$ so ${2\over 6} ={1\over 3}$
what is wrong in this approach , answer given is $3\over 8$ .

Comment: Are you sure about $3/8$? Can you check if you posted the question accurately. This gives $p=1/3$ and not $p=3/8$ as you say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer $1/3$ is correct. The easiest way to see it is to consider the first of $2$, $3$, and $5$ to occur.  (With probability $1$, one of them will eventually occur, so there is a first occurrence.) All three of $2$, $3$, and $5$ have the same probability of occurring first (of those three), so that probability must be $1/3$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** The process is a renewal process since it starts over after each roll (or terminates). So, let $X_1$ denote the result of the first draw and $p$ the required probability. Then you have that $$p=P(X_1=2)+P(X_1=1,4 \text{ or }6)p+P(X_1=3 \text{ or }5)\cdot0$$ 
(can you see why?).